# SUM(COUNT(*)) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle11g

I am using the popular employee table in the HR schema of Oracle. Sample data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPp9a.jpg
I am trying the find out the count as well as the percentage of the people who have the same salary from that table.

However, I am getting error when I try the below query :

```
SELECT SALARY, count(*),((count(*)/sum(count(*))))*100 FROM EMPLOYEES
group by salary;

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

However ,when I try the below query, I get the desired result.

```
SELECT SALARY, count(*),(count(*)/(select sum(count(*)) from employees group by salary))*100 FROM EMPLOYEES
group by salary;
```

Can somebody tell how the achieve my goal using the first query itself? I understand that the count(*) returns many rows, whereas the sum (count(*)) returns just 1 row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `OVER()` clause:

```
SELECT SALARY, count(*),
       count(*) * 100 / sum(count(*)) OVER ()
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY salary;
```

Comment: why aren't we adding any argument in the over() clause. I have used over()  for ranking purposes before but I didn't quite understand the usage here.

Comment: Because you want the sum over of all the rows, so there is no `partition by`.  You don't want a cumulative sum, so there is no `order by`.  However, the `over` is required for a window/analytic function.

Comment: Now when I try to round the %age result SELECT SALARY, count(*),
       round(count(*)*100/sum(count(*))) OVER()
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY salary; I get another error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @aravindnk . . . That was not what was in my answer, even before I fixed the typo.  But the issue is simply balancing the parentheses and including an argument to `count()`.